# Pulling a setState from child component and then using it as a value in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, react-props

I created a stopwatch and I am attempting to take the value of the stopwatch and pass it through a form component.  Currently, when trying to push it through using 'props', it isn't connecting to the specific 'setTime' const determined in the StopWatch component.

I am using react-hook-form, and Styled Components throughout the project. And currently I don't have anything passed through my "value" in my controller because everything I'm trying to do just isn't working.

Here is the stop watch component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const StopWatch = (props) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [timerOn, setTimeOn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 10);
      }, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn]);

  //   const updateTimeLogged = (e) => {
  //     props.setTimeOn(e.target.value);
  //   };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2)}:</span>
        <span>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2)}:</span>
        <span>{("0" + ((time / 10) % 100)).slice(-2)}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        {!timerOn && time === 0 && (
          <button onClick={() => setTimeOn(true)}>Start</button>
        )}
        {timerOn && <button onClick={() => setTimeOn(false)}>Stop</button>}
        {!timerOn && time !== 0 && (
          <button onClick={() => setTimeOn(true)}>Resume</button>
        )}
        {!timerOn && time > 0 && (
          <button onClick={() => setTime(0)}>Reset</button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StopWatch;
```

And here is my form component:

```
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  Input,
  GridContainer,
  Label,
  InputWrapper,
  DateWrapper,
  NotesWrapper,
  StopWatchWrapper,
} from "./PracticeLog.styled";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";
import StopWatch from "./StopWatch";



const PracticeLogInput = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

 

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <DateWrapper>
          <Label>Date</Label>
          <Input type="date" {...register("Date")} placeholder="Date"></Input>
        </DateWrapper>
        <NotesWrapper>
          <Label>Notes</Label>
          <Input type="text" {...register("Notes")} placeholder="Notes"></Input>
        </NotesWrapper>
        <StopWatchWrapper>
          <Controller
            name="time"
            control={control}
            onChange={(e) => setInterval(e.target.value)}
            value={}  //<-- this is where I need to put the value I get from 'setTime' in '/.StopWatch'.
            render={StopWatch}
          />
        </StopWatchWrapper>
        <Button type="Submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default PracticeLogInput;
```

If you see anything I can improve on, please let me know.

Comment: You can define time and setTime in PracticelogInput itself

Comment: Then I would just use props for time and setTime in StopWatch to set the equations?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code but your code is little bit complex try making it simpler bro

```
    import {
  Button,
  Form,
  Input,
  GridContainer,
  Label,
  InputWrapper,
  DateWrapper,
  NotesWrapper,
  StopWatchWrapper,
} from "./PracticeLog.styled";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";
import StopWatch from "./StopWatch";



const PracticeLogInput = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0)
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

 

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <DateWrapper>
          <Label>Date</Label>
          <Input type="date" {...register("Date")} placeholder="Date"></Input>
        </DateWrapper>
        <NotesWrapper>
          <Label>Notes</Label>
          <Input type="text" {...register("Notes")} placeholder="Notes"></Input>
        </NotesWrapper>
        <StopWatchWrapper>
          <Controller
            name="time"
            control={control}
            onChange={(e) => setInterval(e.target.value)}
            value={time}  //<-- this is where I need to put the value I get from 'setTime' in '/.StopWatch'.
            render={<StopWatch
time={time}
setTime={setTime}
/>}
          />
        </StopWatchWrapper>
        <Button type="Submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default PracticeLogInput;
```

And in StopWatch component change the code like this

```
    const StopWatch = (props) => {
      const {time,setTime}=props
      const [timerOn, setTimeOn] = useState(false

);
//rest
```

Note : The flow is like parent to child you can't pull a state from child to parent directly instead define the state in parent and pass it as props to child. And change the state from child using the props itself.

Comment: Thanks, I made the initial changes, but am getting errors. I will spend some time troubleshooting but I think that you've put my mindset in the right direction. Can you elaborate on what makes my code complex?

Comment: What error you are getting. Can you please paste it here

Comment: I am getting 'setTime is not a function'. And when I hover over time and setTime, it's showing the value as 'any' rather than showing me the path back to PracticeLogInput.